# Debian 10 need to change MAC address of interface to connect using Ethernet over USB

Tags: linux, debian, network-interface, networkmanager

everytime that I use the Ethernet over USB connection I need to change the MAC address of the interface to achieve the connection

> macchanger -r enp0s20f0u1

After the change the connection is automattic, but If I disconnect and connect again I need to change the MAC address again.

**Technical details**

- OS: Debian buster (10.3) Kernel: 4.19.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian
  4.19.98-1 (2020-01-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux
- NetworkManager: 1.14.6
- KDE: 5.14.5

Comment: Do you change to a specific mac address or doesn't it matter to which one?   Can you check the DHCP server if the original address has been blocked for any reason?

Comment: I change to random MAC address. I cannot find how to get the blocked MAC address.

Comment: Do you know what the address is before you change it?  What does lsusb tell you about your usb device?

Comment: Before change it 00:00:00:00:00:00 (XEROX CORPORATION). lsusb Bus 001 Device 039: ID 04e8:6863 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy series, misc. (tethering mode)

Comment: OK, so the problem is that there isn't an address at all.

Comment: Well, yes. But it does not save the new address. is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: I haven't found it yet, only this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355936/samsung-s7-android-fails-to-tether-and-not-setting-up-network-configuration   Is rndis_host involved in your configuration?

Comment: from lsmod: usbnet                 49152  2 rndis_host,cdc_ether

Comment: can you check the rndis_host lines in /var/log/messages?   I get "ghp-amdA10 kernel: rndis_host 1-1:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:10.0-1, RNDIS device, 22:06:5a:db:db:04"

Comment: If you would use g_ether iso. cdc_ether, you could fix the mac address: https://support.criticallink.com/redmine/projects/mityarm-5cs/wiki/Hard_setting_RNDIS_MAC_address

Comment: /var/log/messages: rndis_host 1-1:1.0 eth0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, RNDIS device, 00:00:00:00:00:00

Comment: Note that I have tried the suggested link, but it is not worked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running buster 10.4 and possible caveats is I'm running the NetworkManager at all.

In order to get Ethernet over USB to work correctly, I added

```
  g_ether
```

to `/etc/modules` and rebooted with the device connected with a USB cable.

To my surprise, when I typed

```
  ifconfig -a
```

there were now two Ethernet interfaces - the original Ethernet interface

```
 enp0s25
```

and second Ethernet interface.

```
  enx00e02277cd85
```

with a MAC address of `00:e0:22:77:cd:85`.

I simply added the second interface to `/etc/network/interfaces` as

```
    iface enx00e02277cd85 inet static
    address 192.168.2.11
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.2.0
    gateway 192.168.2.1
```

where the gateway address is the IP address of the device I need to access using a USB cable - and rebooted.

And added the IP address to /etc/hosts using the name pluto for convenience.

Also, if you type `ifconfig` at the right moment after you plug in the USB device, the new device starts out as eth0 but is renamed to `enx00e02277cd85`.

My only requirement is to be able to ssh into the device which is ADALM-PLUTO SDR - a full-duplex RF device.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

With a udev rule and a small script, it is possible to assign a fixed Mac Address when the usb tethering is established, as [Mon Bloc-Notes](https://www.monblocnotes.org/node/1895) explains.

Find the serial of your device (in the article it is usb0, yours is eth0 if I'm not mistaken).

```
udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/net/eth0
```

Create or add a new rule to /etc/udev/rules.d/90-local.rules

```
ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="usb", ATTRS{serial}=="xxxx", RUN+="/etc/udev/scripts/android"
```

Create an executable script /etc/udev/scripts/android

```
#!/bin/bash
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig eth0 hw ether 02:11:22:33:44:55
ifconfig eth0 192.168.42.1
ifconfig eth0 up
```

Finally, prevent networkmanager from managing that device  (see link).

Comment: My interface is rename from eth0 to enp0s20f0u1 as new debian does. I tried the solution in the post, but unfortunately it did not work.